# RavenDB 4 - Retrieve index name given its AbstractIndexCreationTask<TDocument, TReduceResult> class implementation

Tags: indexing, ravendb, ravendb4

As for the title, I'm trying to retrieve the name of a specific index at runtime.

The indexes are already registered at application startup with the

```
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(/*[assembly]*/, documentStore);
```

But at query time I need to know (for some specificity of the project...) the actual name of the index that's queried.

I know there's a `GetIndexNamesOperation` but it is just returning an array of string and I'll not be able to associate it with the actual index class...

The ideal would be something operating with the `typeof(IndexClass<T, R>)` where `IndexClass<T, R> : AbstractIndexCreationTask<T, R>`.

I'm searching through the documentations but I'm not finding any clue.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query an index you have the name under IndexName variable.
[image]

Comment: I didn't even think to check there! Thanks!